# Javascript - Sidebar toggle always open

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

So I have this side bar and I want to switch its behaviour.
instead of it being closed like this:

[image]

I want to keep it opened when the website launches like this:

[image]

Here's the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
  $(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggler').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('.navbar-minimal').toggleClass('open');
    })
  });     
</script>
```

And Html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-left navbar-minimal animate" role="navigation" id="sidebar-1">
  <div class="navbar-toggler animate">
    <span class="menu-icon"></span>
    <p id="menutab">Menu</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar-menu animate">
    <li class="dropdown" id="dropdown-nav">
      <a href="#" class="animate dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="desc animate" style="font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;">Top 5 Events</span>
        <span class="mini-icon"><img src="Images/ps/Events.png" id="mini-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="events">
        <iframe src="Php/events.php" id="iframe" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto">
          <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-left navbar-minimal animate"
```

go to the above line in your html markup and add the class "**open**" like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-left navbar-minimal animate open"
```

So it will be opened by default.

Comment: Wow... that easy! haha Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(function () {
        $(this).closest('.navbar-minimal').toggleClass('open');
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add class open to navbar-menu by which it show open and when you click close to menu its toggele the element ul.navbar-menu

```
 $(".navbar-toggler").click(function () {
    $(".navbar-menu").slideToggle();
   });
```